# Set nginx root to a public folder while keeping the parent directory name in the URL

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

In our web project we have a a directory called `public`. We set the `root` in the nginx config to this `public` folder so that only the files in the `public` folder are accessible through the URL.

Our config looks somewhat like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com

    root   /srv/nginx/example.com/v1/public;
    index  index.html index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
    }
}
```

So now we can access `srv/nginx/example.com/v1/public` through the URL `example.com`. Great.

But how can we set our URLs to `example.com/v1` with the root at `/srv/nginx/example.com/v1/public`? Also if we upload a new version it should be available through the URL with `example.com/v2` with the root at `/srv/nginx/example.com/v2/public` without changing config files.

One way I think I can achieve this is by making multiple server blocks each time we upload a new version. But like I said I don't wish to change the nginx config each time we upload a new version and have the risk of doing something wrong.

What other ways are there? And how can I use these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [regular expression `location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) to split the URI into two components and use an [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) to construct the path to the target file (which is represented by the [`$request_filename` variable](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_request_filename)).

For example:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com

    root   /var/empty;
    index  index.html index.php;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;

    location ~ ^/(?<prefix>[^/]+)/(?<suffix>.*)$ {
        alias /srv/nginx/example.com/$prefix/public/$suffix;

        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /$prefix/index.php last; }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            fastcgi_pass   php-fpm;
        }
    }
}
```

Avoid the use of `try_file` with `alias` due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97). See [this caution](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/) on the use of `if`.